# How to check if ANY php parameter exists in url

Tags: php, html

I am making a forum that accesses threads based off the category in the URL using the GET method. I want to redirect to an error page if no parameters exist in the url, but I want this to be a generic piece of code that can be used around my whole site.

For example:

The url would normally contain the category id:

```
localhost/myforum/threads.php?categoryid=1
```

I want it so that when the url is:

```
localhost/myforum/threads.php
```

it is to redirect to an error page, and that this piece of code is usable all around the website

Comment: There is the answer in your question. Check $_GET array, or http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php.

Answer (score 7):

The most reliable way is to check if the URL contains a question mark:

```php
if (false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')) {
    // There is a query string (including cases when it's empty)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$gets = parse_url($url));
if($gets['query'] == "")
{
    echo "No GET variables";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
if (empty(array_diff($_GET, ['']))) {
    header("Location: /path/to/error.php");
}
```

EDIT: Updated to remove empty values

Comment: please add a closing parenthesis after the empty call to close the if condition.

Comment: @TurboPT Missed that, thanks.

Comment: @PedroLobito It returns true.

Comment: @PedroLobito True as well, as it's suppose to. What point are you trying to make?

Comment: I'll give 1+ for the simplicity, well done, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_set to check if the parameter exists like this,

```
isset($_GET)
```

Comment: `isset` not `is_set` and this will only check for a parameter called categoryid, not others.